# Why is Chainlink oracle function call failing?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

While attempting to fund me contract is tell me it encountered an error without specifying the error. I attempted to fund 0.1 eth through the fund function, and in the terminal it says:

```
[block:8404521 txIndex:12]
from: 0x8a9...e4303
to: FundMe.fund() 0x542...E109C
value: 100000000000000000 wei
data: 0xb60...d4288
logs: 0
hash: 0x29a...97939
```

and in the etherscan it says:status fail :

```
Contract 0x5422f3458be343e378e7a399e16fff548e7e109c
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
```

I tried looking for problems with my code and found none.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
//import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol"; won't need in later complier versions.
contract FundMe {
    

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require( getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,"You need to send more Eth");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
        (,int256 answer,,,)=priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
    //10000000000 = Gwei which is why we added 10 zeros to getPrice(answer) to convert it to Wei amount
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount)/ 1000000000000000000; //divide 2x because we added 10*((getPrice)answer))
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Aggregator contract address "0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419" belongs to [mainnet](https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd/eth-usd)

[From here](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses/) get the `ETH/USD` goerli testnet address:"0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e"

- Now in order to call chainlink oracle you have to have `LINK` token in your contract. Get some link token to your conract address [from the faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/)
- Import the token in metamask. you will see the amount
- send link token from your metamask to your contract
- deploy your contract. if you are using `Remix IDE` chose the `injected provider` to connect to metamask. Because chainlink contract is on goerli, so you need to be on Goerli testnet. Once deployment goes through you can call the `fund` function.
- Since the `fund` function has no argument, you need to send the value alongside the transaction. That is why inside the function you have `msg.value` to access to the sent amount.
- In `Remix` ide, under "GAS LIMIT`input there is`VALUE`input. you need to pass the amount in there before you call the`fund` function.